# Story about a girl surviving a nuclear bomb in an isolated rural town

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book in English class at school around 1997/1998, about a girl who is the only survivor in a post nuclear war. The girl lives on a small farm and has somehow managed to avoid radiation, she has a .22 rifle for hunting/defence.
There is a man in a Biohazard suit that turns up at her house and she believes he is a scientist, he turns out to be a murderer that stole the suit and made his way out of the war zone to the farm. The girl realises this as she finds bullet holes in his suit once he has taken it off and hung it up in the house.
It then becomes a fight for survival for the girl...
We didn't finish the story at school for some reason, I can't remember any of the names to help either.

Comment: This kind of sounds like [Emergence](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2300.Emergence) by David R. Palmer.  Emergence doesn't have a nuclear war of a biohazard suit though, so I can't really raise this as an answer.  Very good book though, thank you for reminding me of it.

Comment: Emergence sounds similar, but after reading the description on Wiki I realised it's not the one...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This sounds like [**Z for Zachariah**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_for_Zachariah) by Robert C. O'Brien. Some of the details are slightly different (the man in the suit is actually a scientist) but the broad outline matches your description.

Comment: That's the story, it was a long time ago that I read it so some details were wrong in my description. Thanks